# When submitting an application to apple, is it necessary to have all resources in the projects resource folder?

Tags: xcode, filesystems, appstore-approval

In the past, whenever I have added a file to my resources I haven't checked the box that says "Copy items into destination groups folder if needed". Someone told me that wasn't necessary. But I am beginning to wonder. All of my resources are using the path type "relative to project". When I open my xcode project, all my files apear under the resources folder. But when I open my game's folder in finder, the resources folder is empty. Does this mean that when I submit it to apple the resources won't be there and it will crash? If so, is there an easy way to fix this or do I have to move all my referenced files into the destination groups folder manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only submitting your compiled binary to Apple, not your source code or project directory.